InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged) not working on Blazor App
I am trying to build a web page that displays a few values. Currently they are being sent to an API but I modified the original application so they are sent to a localhost route. I simply want to display them in a web page so another screen capture program can read them. It's for a golf simulator.
So the values will be updated every 30 seconds maybe and I simply want the new values to appear on the page. Nothing fancy, just numbers and their titles.
However, I'm just a materials scientist turned data engineer so my dev process has mostly been dialogue with ChatGPT as I have simply very little clue about C#, Blazor and all the other stuff. I am also not interested in taking 5 days of learning all the details of the framework, I just want a few numbers to be displayed. I guess it's a pretty "simple" mistake but I just don't know the issue behind it.
I guess the project could be better structured, but the issue is the following: I start the application, works fine. localhost shows "Loading..." as designed. However, when I send a curl request, nothing happens. If I reload the page, the values are displayed as designed. However, I want them to be updated without manual refresh. I also couldn't even get the page to refresh manually.
Logs first, then code.
// Starting the app, opening localhost:8080
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
SignalR connection established.
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[100]
      Start processing HTTP request GET http://localhost:8080/wurstbrot
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET http://localhost:8080/wurstbrot
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 2046.5032ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 2080.0127ms - 200
Raw JSON Response: []
// sending curl request curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/wurstbrot -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @data.json
// nothing happens in the browser window, but log says 
Received update from server: [{"headline":"ClubSpeed","num":120.5}, [more data...]]
OnInitializedAsync
// even did more logging earlier and it reaches all code points that it should (I'll mark it in Home.razor below)
// Now I hit F5 and voila, the numbers appear and...
SignalR connection established.
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[100]
      Start processing HTTP request GET http://localhost:8080/wurstbrot
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[100]
      Sending HTTP request GET http://localhost:8080/wurstbrot
Raw JSON Response: [{"headline":"ClubSpeed","num":120.5},{"headline":"HLA","num":5.2},{"headline":"VLA","num":15.765432},{"headline":"Speed","num":160.8},{"headline":"BackSpin","num":3000.0},{"headline":"SideSpin","num":-150.0},{"headline":"TotalSpin","num":3200.0},{"headline":"SpinAxis","num":45.0},{"headline":"ShotNumber","num":23}]
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
      Received HTTP response headers after 2013.3491ms - 200
info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler[101]
      End processing HTTP request after 2013.6284ms - 200

Here are the relevant files. I wish I could somehow narrow it down to a certain point in the code but I feel like I've tried every possible line that seems to me as it could have any impact on the issue. I just left most of the ChatGPT comments in, want to clean all that up as soon as I can get it to work.
Home.razor (the only page as I don't even need fancy navigating or so...)
@page "/"

@using System;
@using System.Text.Json;
@using ValueKing.Services;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

@inject HttpClient Http
@inject AppStateService AppState

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

@if (AppState.Values == null || !AppState.Values.Any())
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; gap: 16px;">
        @foreach (var value in AppState.Values)
        {
            <div style="flex: 1 1 calc(33.333% - 16px); border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 8px; border-radius: 4px;">
                <h3>@value.Headline</h3>
                <p>@(value.Num?.ToString("F2") ?? "0.00")</p>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}

@code {
    private HubConnection? hubConnection;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (hubConnection == null)
        {
            // Initialize SignalR connection
            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl($"http://localhost:8080/datahub")
                .Build();
        }
        // Handle updates from the server
        hubConnection.On<string>("UpdateData", async (jsonData) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Received update from server: {jsonData}");

            // Deserialize updated data and refresh UI
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
            try
            {
                var updatedValues = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<APIValues>>(jsonData, options);
                if (updatedValues != null)
                {
                    await InvokeAsync(() =>
                    {
                        // CONSOLE OUTPUT HERE IS WRITTEN AT CURL REQUEST
                        Console.WriteLine($"OnInitializedAsync");
                        StateChanged(updatedValues);
                        // CONSOLE OUTPUT HERE IS ALSO WRITTEN AT CURL REQUEST
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    await InvokeAsync(() =>
                    {
                        StateChanged(new List<APIValues>());
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error deserializing update: {ex.Message}");
            }
        });

        try
        {
            // Start SignalR connection
            await hubConnection.StartAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("SignalR connection established.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error connecting to SignalR hub: {ex.Message}");
        }

        // Fetch initial data via HTTP GET request
        await FetchInitialDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task FetchInitialDataAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            // Fetch the JSON response as a string
            HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.GetAsync("http://localhost:8080/wurstbrot");

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Raw JSON Response: {jsonResponse}");

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonResponse))
                {
                    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

                    try
                    {
                        // Deserialize the JSON into the values list
                        var fetchedValues = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<APIValues>>(jsonResponse, options);
                        if (fetchedValues != null)
                        {
                            await InvokeAsync(() =>
                            {
                                StateChanged(fetchedValues);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Deserialization error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Response JSON is empty or null.");
                    await InvokeAsync(() =>
                    {
                        StateChanged(new List<APIValues>());
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"HTTP request failed with status code {response.StatusCode}");
                await InvokeAsync(() =>
                {
                    StateChanged(new List<APIValues>());
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while fetching initial data: {ex.Message}");
            await InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateChanged(new List<APIValues>());
            });
        }
    }

    private void StateChanged(List<APIValues> newValues)
    {
        AppState.Values = newValues;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (hubConnection != null)
        {
            await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}

AppStateService.cs
using ValueKing.Services;

public class AppStateService
{
    private List<APIValues> _values = new List<APIValues>();

    public List<APIValues> Values
    {
        get => _values;
        set
        {
            if (!AreValuesEqual(_values, value)) // Only update if values differ
            {
                _values = value ?? new List<APIValues>(); // Ensure values are never null
            }
        }
    }

    // Helper method to compare lists
    private static bool AreValuesEqual(IReadOnlyList<APIValues> list1, IReadOnlyList<APIValues> list2)
    {
        // bla bla
    }
}

WurstbrotController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace ValueKing.Controller
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WurstbrotController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static string _jsonStore = "[]";
        private readonly IHubContext<DataHub> _hubContext;

        public WurstbrotController(IHubContext<DataHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hubContext));
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            // Ensure the response is JSON content
            return Content(_jsonStore, "application/json");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] object? jsonPayload)
        {
            if (jsonPayload == null)
            {
                // bla
            }

            try
            {
                // Serialize the JSON payload safely
                _jsonStore = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonPayload);

                // Notify all clients of the update
                await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("UpdateData", _jsonStore);

                // Return success response
                return Ok(new { Message = "JSON successfully updated.", Data = _jsonStore });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // bla
            }
        }
    }
}

DataService.cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace ValueKing.Services
{
    public class APIValues
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("headline")]
        public string? Headline { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("num")]
        public double? Num { get; set; }

        // Parameterless constructor required for deserialization
        public APIValues() { }

        public APIValues(string? headline, double? num)
        {
            Headline = headline ?? "empty";
            Num = num ?? 0.0;
        }

        // Override Equals for meaningful equality
        public override bool Equals(object? obj)
        {
            if (obj is APIValues other)
            {
                return string.Equals(Headline, other.Headline, StringComparison.Ordinal)
                       && Nullable.Equals(Num, other.Num);
            }
            return false;
        }

        // Override GetHashCode to ensure consistency with Equals
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return HashCode.Combine(Headline?.GetHashCode(StringComparison.Ordinal), Num);
        }
    }

    [Route("/api")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DataController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public APIValues GetData([FromBody] APIValues values)
        {
            var data = new APIValues(values.Headline, values.Num);
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            return data;
        }
    }
}

DataHub.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

public class DataHub : Hub
{
    // Define any server-to-client communication logic if needed
}


Blazor WebAssembly or Server?  If you use server this is a lot easier.
